# Add popups and custom marker colors to Folium's FastMarkerCluster using FeatureGroupSubGroups

Tags: python, folium, leaflet.markercluster, folium-plugins

Using folium in Python, I am trying to render 10K+ markers with associated tooltips and popups (popups are pngs converted to an Iframe). Markers/Popups are associated with specific FeatureGroupSubGroups for display purposes in the layer control and to control marker colors. With fewer points (~5K), the map renders, but with my markers now exceeding 10K, the HTML no longer renders. I understand the the FastMarkerCluster is likely what I need to use, but I want to maintain all of the functionality as I currently have with MarkerCluster. My understanding is I need to store my lat/lon locatins, the popups, and the colors, and then create a callback function function all to be passed into the FastMarkerCluster. So my questions:

1. How to create a callback function that accepts the lat/lon pairs, the color, and popups
2. How to keep the markers associated with a specific fmap such that the markerclusters are dynamically updated when selecting/de-selecting individualy Feature
   GroupSubGroup(s).

My code is below, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8


import folium
import base64
from folium import IFrame
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import sys
import glob
import os.path
from folium import plugins
#
popups = list()
lats   = list() #np.empty(0)
lons   = list() #np.empty(0)
colors = list()
names  = list()

coords = []
ipopup = 0
mkr1 = list() # list of the individual markers
mkrc = list() # list of the individual markers for the marker cluster (in case we need to access them separately)
#
#path to plots
path = './'
# Styles for the AQI contours
style_mod = {'fillColor': '#FFFF00', 'lineColor': '#FFFF00', 'color' : '#FFFF00'}
style_uns = {'fillColor': '#ff7e00', 'lineColor': '#ff7e00', 'color' : '#ff7e00'}
style_unh = {'fillColor': '#FF0000', 'lineColor': '#FF0000', 'color' : '#FF0000'}
style_vuh = {'fillColor': '#8f3f97', 'lineColor': '#8f3f97', 'color' : '#8f3f97'}
style_haz = {'fillColor': '#7e0023', 'lineColor': '#7e0023', 'color' : '#7e0023'}
#defining the resolution, width, and height of the popup
resolution, width, height = 42, 12, 6
marker_radius=8
#
#defining plot type
plot_type = "grp1.timeseries"
#import variables from the bash file
start_date=sys.argv[1]
end_date=sys.argv[2]
todays_date=sys.argv[3]
noaa_only = sys.argv[4] # no longer necessary, just check for the exisitence of > #CONUS+R1-R10 = 11 plots (only CONUS for AOD) 
species_list = ['PM25', 'OZONE', 'PM10', 'CO', 'NO2', 'AOD550', 'temp', 'dew_pt_temp', 'ws', 'wdir', 'precip_1hr']
color_list   = ['purple', 'blue', 'red', 'green' , 'yellow', 'orange', 'cyan', 'blueviolet', 'limegreen', 'maroon', 'gray', 'sienna']
network_list = ['EPA AirNOW', 'EPA AirNOW','EPA AirNOW','EPA AirNOW','EPA AirNOW','EPA AirNOW','NASA AERONET','NOAA ISD','NOAA ISD','NOAA ISD','NOAA ISD','NOAA ISD']
airnow_species = ['PM2.5', 'OZONE', 'PM10', 'CO', 'NO2']
ish_species = ['temp', 'dew_pt_temp', 'ws', 'wdir', 'precip_1hr']
ish_dict = dict()
fmap_dict = dict()
# First create the BASE folium map centered over the US
fmap = folium.Map(location=[40, -95],zoom_start=4,min_zoom=3,control=False)
# Next create the feature groups that will hold the AIRNOW and ISH-LITE PLOTS
fmap_airnow = folium.FeatureGroup(name='EPA AirNOW AQI',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
#fmap_ish_lite = folium.FeatureGroup(name="NOAA Integrated Surface Database",overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
#fmap_aeronet = folium.FeatureGroup(name="NASA AERONET",overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
# Now create the marker cluster group (not a feature group or featuregroupsubgroup)
fmap_marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(name='Station Decluster Tool (Experimental)',control=False,show=True,overlay=True) #disableClusterAtZoom=16
# Add the Feature Groups and the Marker Cluster Groups as children to the main map
fmap.add_child(fmap_airnow)
#fmap.add_child(fmap_ish_lite)
for s in range(len(species_list)):
        print("now working on "+species_list[s])
        species=species_list[s]
        #
        # Create feature groups for each species
        if species == "PM25":
                # Check to see if files exists before creating the layer
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.PM2.5*')) < 12:
                        print("not enough files present")
                        continue
                else:
                        print("continuing with " + species)
                        fmap_pm25_aqi = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_airnow,name='PM2.5 AQI',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_pm25_aqi)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_pm25_aqi]
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Moderate.pm25*json'):
                                fmap_pm25_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_mod))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'UnhealthySG.pm25*json'):
                                fmap_pm25_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_uns))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Unhealthy.pm25*json'):
                                fmap_pm25_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_unh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'VeryUnhealthy.pm25*json'):
                                fmap_pm25_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_vuh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Hazardous.pm25*json'):
                                fmap_pm25_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_haz))
                        fmap_pm25 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='PM2.5',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_pm25)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_pm25]
        if species == "OZONE":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.OZONE*')) < 12:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_ozone_aqi = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_airnow,name='Ozone AQI',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_ozone_aqi)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_ozone_aqi]
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Moderate.ozone*json'):
                                fmap_ozone_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_mod))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'UnhealthySG.ozone*json'):
                                fmap_ozone_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_uns))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Unhealthy.ozone*json'):
                                fmap_ozone_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_unh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'VeryUnhealthy.ozone*json'):
                                fmap_ozone_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_vuh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Hazardous.ozone*json'):
                                fmap_ozone_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_haz))
                        fmap_combined_aqi = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_airnow,name='Ozone + PM2.5 AQI',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_combined_aqi)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_ozone_aqi]
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Moderate.combined*json'):
                                fmap_combined_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_mod))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'UnhealthySG.combined*json'):
                                fmap_combined_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_uns))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Unhealthy.combined*json'):
                                fmap_combined_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_unh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'VeryUnhealthy.combined*json'):
                                fmap_combined_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_vuh))
                        for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Hazardous.combined*json'):
                                fmap_combined_aqi.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=(open(filename,"r",encoding="utf-8-sig")).read(),style_function=lambda x:style_haz))
                        fmap_ozone = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='Ozone',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_ozone)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_ozone]
  if species == "PM10":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.PM10*')) < 12:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_pm10 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='PM10',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_pm10)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_pm10]
        if species == "CO":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.CO*')) < 12:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_co = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='CO',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_co)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_co]
        if species == "NO2":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.NO2*')) < 12:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_no2 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='NO2',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_no2)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_no2]
        if species == "TEMP":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.TEMP*')) < 12:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_TEMP = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='2-m Temperature',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'EPA AirNOW' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'].append(fmap_TEMP)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['EPA AirNOW'] = [fmap_TEMP]
        if species == "AOD550":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.aod_550nm*')) < 2:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_aod = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='AERONET AOD @ 550nm',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NASA AERONET' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NASA AERONET'].append(fmap_aod)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NASA AERONET'] = [fmap_aod]
        if species == "temp":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.temp*')) < 1:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_temp = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='2-m Temperature (ISD)',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NOAA ISD' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'].append(fmap_temp)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'] = [fmap_temp]
        if species == "dew_pt_temp":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.dew_pt_temp*')) < 1:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_dpt = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='Dew Pt. Temp',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NOAA ISD' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'].append(fmap_dpt)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'] = [fmap_dpt]
        if species == "ws":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.ws*')) < 1:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_ws = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='Wind Speed',overlay=True,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NOAA ISD' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'].append(fmap_ws)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'] = [fmap_ws]
        if species == "wdir":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.wdir*')) < 1:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_wdir = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='Wind Direction',overlay=False,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NOAA ISD' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'].append(fmap_wdir)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'] = [fmap_wdir]
        if species == "precip_1hr":
                if len(glob.glob('plot_grp1.timeseries.precip_1hr*')) < 1:
                        continue
                else:
                        fmap_precip1hr = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fmap_marker_cluster,name='Precip (1hr)',overlay=False,control=True,show=True)
                        if 'NOAA ISD' in fmap_dict:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'].append(fmap_precip1hr)
                        else:
                                fmap_dict['NOAA ISD'] = [fmap_precip1hr]




        #get the site names from the txt file
        fileObj = open("sitefile.txt."+species+"."+todays_date, "r") #opens the file in read mode
        site_name_list = fileObj.read().splitlines() #puts the file into an array
        fileObj.close()
        ##remove the extra characters from either end
        site_name_list = [site[1:-1] for site in site_name_list]
        ##replace the spaces in the site names with underscores
        site_name = [site.replace(' ','_') for site in site_name_list]

        #have to change the PM variable name
        if species == 'PM25':
                species = 'PM2.5'
        if species == 'AOD550':
                species = 'aod_550nm'

        #defining arrays for the lat and lon
        ##reading in the airnow file
        if species == "aod_550nm":
                data = xr.open_dataset("test5.aeronet."+todays_date+".nc")
                latitude = data['latitude'].values
                longitude = data['longitude'].values
                site = data['siteid'].values
        if str(species) in airnow_species:
                data = xr.open_dataset("test5.airnow."+todays_date+".nc")
                latitude = data['latitude'].values[0]
                longitude = data['longitude'].values[0]
                site = data['site'].values[0]
        if str(species) in ish_species:
                data = xr.open_dataset("test5.ish."+todays_date+".nc")
                latitude = data['latitude'].values
                longitude = data['longitude'].values
                site = data['siteid'].values
        ##loop through the sites with plots
        for i in range(len(site_name)):

                #boolean to identify the index of each site
                sitename_bool = site == site_name_list[i]

        #use the boolean to select the lat and lon corresponding to each site
                site_lat = latitude[sitename_bool]
                site_lon = longitude[sitename_bool]

                #define the plot name
                if species == "aod_550nm":
                        plot_name="plot_" + plot_type + "." + species + "." + start_date + "_00." + end_date + "_00.siteid." + site_name[i] + ".png"
                if str(species) in airnow_species:
                        plot_name="plot_" + plot_type + "." + species + "." + start_date + "_00." + end_date + "_00.site." + site_name[i] + ".png"
                if str(species) in ish_species:
                        plot_name="plot_" + plot_type + "." + species + "." + start_date + "_00." + end_date + "_00.siteid." + site_name[i] + ".png"

                #resizing the image to fit the popup window size and saving as another file
                ##needs to be in loop
                if os.path.exists(path + plot_name) and os.path.getsize(path+plot_name) != 0:
                        image = Image.open(path + plot_name) #path to original image file
                        image = image.resize(((width*resolution),(height*resolution)),Image.ANTIALIAS)
                        image.save(fp = path + plot_name) #save back to the original directory? or new

                        # opening the resized plot and encoding it
                        png = path + plot_name
                        # Encoding it
                        encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read())

                        # formating the encoded plot as html
                        html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format

                        # decoding the plot into an iframe
                        iframe = IFrame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20)

                        #creating a popup of the iframe
                        popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650,sticky=True)
                        popups.append(popup)
                        lats.append(site_lat[0])
                        lons.append(site_lon[0])
                        ipopup = ipopup + 1
                        tooltip = folium.Tooltip(str(site_name[i]))
                        names.append(str(site_name[i]))
                        #
                        if species == "OZONE":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'blue', fill_color="blue", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'blue', fill_color="blue", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_ozone.add_child(x)
                        if species == "PM10":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'red', fill_color="red", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'red', fill_color="red", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_pm10.add_child(x)
                        if species == "CO":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'green', fill_color="green", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'green', fill_color="green", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_co.add_child(x)
                        if species == "NO2":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'yellow', fill_color="yellow", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'yellow', fill_color="yellow", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_no2.add_child(x)
                        if species == "TEMP":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'orange', fill_color="orange", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'orange', fill_color="orange", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_TEMP.add_child(x)
                        if species == "aod_550nm":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'cyan', fill_color="cyan", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'cyan', fill_color="cyan", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_aod.add_child(x)
                        if species == "PM2.5":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'purple', fill_color="purple", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'purple', fill_color="purple", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_pm25.add_child(x)
                        if species == "temp":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'blueviolet', fill_color="blueviolet", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'blueviolet', fill_color="blueviolet", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_temp.add_child(x)
                        if species == "dew_pt_temp":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'limegreen', fill_color="limegreen", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'limegreen', fill_color="limegreen", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_dpt.add_child(x)
                        if species == "ws":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'maroon', fill_color="maroon", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'maroon', fill_color="maroon", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_ws.add_child(x)
                        if species == "wdir":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'gray', fill_color="gray", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'gray', fill_color="gray", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_wdir.add_child(x)
                        if species == "precip_1hr":
                                x = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'sienna', fill_color="sienna", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                #y = folium.CircleMarker(location=[site_lat[-1], site_lon[-1]], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, radius=marker_radius,color = 'sienna', fill_color="sienna", fill_opacity=0.5)
                                fmap_precip1hr.add_child(x)
                        mkr1.append(x)
                        colors.append(color_list[s])
#                       mkrc.append(y)
#                       if str(species) in ish_species:
#                       fmap_marker_cluster.add_child(x)
#                       mySubGroup.add_child(x)
#
#
#for i in range(len(lats)):
#       coords.append([lats[i], lons[i]])
fmap.add_child(fmap_marker_cluster)
#fmap.add_child(mySubGroup)
if 'fmap_ozone_aqi' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_ozone_aqi)
if 'fmap_pm25_aqi' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_pm25_aqi)
if 'fmap_combined_aqi' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_combined_aqi)
if 'fmap_ozone' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_ozone)
        fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_ozone)
if 'fmap_pm25' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_pm25)
        fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_pm25)
if 'fmap_pm10' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_pm10)
        fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_pm10)
if 'fmap_co' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_co)
        fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_co)
if 'fmap_no2' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_no2)
        fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_no2)
if 'fmap_TEMP' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_TEMP)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_TEMP)
if 'fmap_aod' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_aod)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_aod)
if 'fmap_temp' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_temp)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_temp)
if 'fmap_dpt' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_dpt)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_dpt)
if 'fmap_ws' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_ws)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_ws)
if 'fmap_wdir' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_wdir)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_wdir)
if 'fmap_precip1hr' in locals():
        fmap.add_child(fmap_precip1hr)
#       fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_precip1hr)
#
fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_airnow)
fmap.keep_in_front(fmap_marker_cluster)
# Add the layer controls
folium.plugins.GroupedLayerControl(fmap_dict, exclusive_groups=False).add_to(fmap)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(fmap)
#saving the map to an html file
output_name = "fullhtml_sfc_f000.html"
fmap.save(output_name)
```

Comment: @ghybs - or anyone?

Comment: @Filip Michalsky - maybe you can help?